# Soft keyboard not showing in custom dialog fragment

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

I have custom dialog fragment with view pager in it, in view pager has an edit text. When custom dialog fragment showing, the edit text has focus but soft keyboard not showing for input.

xml layout of dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:htdu87="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.htdu87.ekaraoke"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/background_app" >

    <!-- <com.htdu87.ekaraoke.objects.LikeComment 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/htdu87_like_comment"/> -->

    <com.htdu87.ekaraoke.classes.MyViewPager 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        htdu87:allow_sweep="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

java code

```
package com.htdu87.ekaraoke.classes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.htdu87.ekaraoke.R;
import com.htdu87.ekaraoke.adapters.ViewPagerAdapter;
import com.htdu87.ekaraoke.configs.AppConfig;

public class LikeCommentDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private long postId;
    private final String COMMENT = "Comment";
    private final String LIKE = "Like";
    private ListView lstComment;
    private ListView lstLike;
    private ImageButton btnPos;
    private EditText txtComment;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterComment;

    public LikeCommentDialogFragment(){

    }


    public void setPostId(long id){
        postId = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View likeCommentDlg = inflater.inflate(R.layout.like_comment_dialog, null); 

        MyViewPager viewPager = (MyViewPager)likeCommentDlg.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        MyFragment frg = new MyFragment();
        frg.setViewResourceId(R.layout.comment);
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(frg, COMMENT).commit();

        frg = new MyFragment();
        frg.setViewResourceId(R.layout.like);
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(frg, LIKE).commit();

        ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), new String[]{COMMENT, LIKE});
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        new LoadComment().execute();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(likeCommentDlg);
        Dialog d = builder.create();
        d.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        return d;
    }

    private class LoadComment extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>{
        private List<String> data;

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String url = AppConfig.SERVER_URL + "load_comment.php?postid="+postId+"&tokent="+AppConfig.TOKENT;
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                if(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
                    if(!httpResponse.getFirstHeader("Content-Type").getValue().equals("application/json; charset=utf8"))
                        return -1;
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
                    JSONArray comments = jsonObj.getJSONArray("comments");
                    int count = comments.length();
                    data = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                        JSONObject commentObj = comments.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject comment = commentObj.getJSONObject("comment");
                        data.add(comment.getString("commentcontent"));
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
                return -2;
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return -3;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            View v = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(COMMENT).getView();
            lstComment = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.lst_comment);
            txtComment = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_comment);

            btnPos = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_post_comment);
            //btnPos.setOnClickListener(LikeComment.this);
            LinearLayout layLoading = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.lay_loading);

            adapterComment = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
            lstComment.setAdapter(adapterComment);
            layLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            txtComment.requestFocus();
            //InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            //imm.showSoftInput(txtComment, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

xml containt edit text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lst_comment"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lay_write_comment"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/lay_write_comment">

        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:hint="@string/str_your_commnet"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/txt_comment"
            android:background="#ffffff"/>

        <ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_button_login"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:contentDescription="@string/str_post_comment"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_post_comment"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lay_loading"
        android:background="@color/background_app"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ProgressBar 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/str_load_comment"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this answer, with a `ListView` rather than a `ViewPager`, could help you?

[Soft Keyboard Doesnt show when using adapter in DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250931/soft-keyboard-doesnt-show-when-using-adapter-in-dialogfragment/26400540#26400540)

Answer (score 0):

make it sure that you haven't used edit text of `android:inputType="none"`
and havn't used this in manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"`

Comment: Thanks, but not resolved my problem, key board still not showing