# Soft Keyboard Doesnt show when using adapter in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-dialogfragment

I have a custom DialogFragment which has an ArrayAdapter in it which has some editTexts in it. When the dialog is shown the soft keyboard does not appear even if i press on the edit text. The edit text does take focus but the keyboard never comes up.

If i do not use an adapter and just use a view with an edit text it works perfectly but as soon as i add the adapter i get the issue.

My code is below. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

```
public class ParameterDialog extends DialogFragment {
Context context;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ArrayList<Parameter> params = this.getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(MainActivity.KEY_PARAMS_TO_DIALOG);
    String name = this.getArguments().getString(MainActivity.KEY_NAME_TO_DIALOG);

    context = getActivity();
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    ParameterDialogAdapter pda = new ParameterDialogAdapter(context,R.layout.parameter_config_string , params);

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder
            .setTitle(name)
            .setAdapter(pda,null)
            .setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });

    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}}
```

-

```
public class ParameterDialogAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Parameter> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<Parameter> data= null;

public ParameterDialogAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Parameter> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    //ParameterHolder holder = null;
    final LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    final int p =position;
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
    return row;
}}
```

-Layout

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/paramValueHolder"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/paramValue"
    android:hint="Value"
    android:textColor="@color/text_grey" />
```

-Code to Show Dialog

```
ParameterDialog pDialog = new ParameterDialog ();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(KEY_NAME_TO_DIALOG,action.getName());
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_PARAMS_TO_DIALOG, params);
        pDialog.setArguments(bundle);

        pDialog.setArguments(bundle);
        pDialog.show(ft, "parameter_dialog");
```

Comment: is it necessary to use an adapter? - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876624/multiple-edittext-objects-in-alertdialog

Comment: Hi unfortunately yes. Above is a simplified example that demonstrates the issue I have. My actual code is more complex and an adapter seems like the best way to do it. If all else fails I guess I'll have to remove it.

Answer (score 14):

I have come across a similar problem while using a `FragmentDialog` containing a `ListView`. The items in the `ListView` contained `EditText` widgets that did not bring up the soft keyboard.

A workaround I discovered was to place an invisible `EditText` within the root layout of the `FragmentDialog`.

For example:

list_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@android:id/list"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

DialogFragment creates the views as follows:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View listLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
    mListView = (ListView) listLayout.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(listLayout).create();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //set adapter
    mListView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: what's the logic behind this?

Comment: Its worked, but what is the logic behind it, still i am not able to understand.

Comment: Magic may work for a while but one day it won't and you  just postponed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

set block descendants property true of your list_item_layout file..
i hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I added android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to the root linear layout but that still doesnt bring up the keyboard and prevents me from focusing on the edit text.