# Soft Keyboard does not show up on EditText RecyclerView in a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to create a DialogFragment that contains a RecyclerView of EditTexts. It scrolls and the Copy/Cut/Paste appears when I click on an EditText but the keyboard never appears. The adapter works since I tried implementing the RecyclerView in an Activity.

I already tried finding solutions for making the keyboard show up such as adding this in the XML

```
</request focus>
```

or this to the dialog

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

but still, none works.

Thank you so much.

additional: here's how it currently appears

[image]

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Looks like a bug on the platform

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 13):

I know this question was asked one year ago, but I asked this very same question today, so it seems that this question is still puzzling people...

Anyways, I came across multiple "solutions" after browsing Stack Overflow and the Android API reference, but only one that would work. Now I'm not sure why these other, seemingly good solutions, wouldn't work for me. But at least I think I understand (or I have a theory) why the solution that finally worked, worked.

NOTE! This solution may not work if you are using some other way to create your dialog in `onCreateDialog(Bundle)` than by utilizing `AlertDialog` and its `AlertDialog.Builder`.

[Here is the solution that worked for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26400540/9235291)

By doing as above solution suggests, you are "tricking" the `AlertDialog` into setting the right flags for you. I'm not saying it's bad code practice, but it may not be the ideal code practice. For those of you not just looking for a quick solution but prepared to dive deep into this matter, continue reading:

So according to [AlertDialog's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html), `AlertDialog` automatically sets some window placement -related flags based on if any views in the dialog return true from `View.onCheckIsTextEditor()`. This behaviour of `AlertLayout` is brought up by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9118027/9235291) that seems to have helped a lot of people asking the same question but without a `RecyclerView` involved and with only `AlertDialog` involved, not `AlertDialog` used by a `DialogFragment` subclass.

You might get the latter solution working (check out its most up-voted comment), but your DialogFragment subclass must provide a way, *after* the `DialogFragment` has been shown, to get the `AlertDialog`'s window, so that you can modify its flags. I haven't tried this, as my `DialogFragment` doesn't provide that functionality.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem when using a `RecyclerView.Adapter`, in a `view` that is created for a class that extends a `DialogFragment`. Also, in my `ViewHolder` I use an `EditText` that was not showing the keyboard when it gets focus.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext());
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_text_detected_list, null);
    //{...setAdapter, and other setups...}
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.setView(view).create();

    //The below line, solves my problem with the keyboard not showing up
    dialog.setOnShowListener(d -> dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM));
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for `dialog.setOnShowListener` suggestion, Thx for saving my day @FelipeFerreira :)

Comment: Saved my day. Even with the `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` this hack is still needed. Android development is a miserable experience.

Comment: After a day of trying this and that, this answer saved me. Most straightforward way.

Answer (score 6):

a) Force the input method open.

```
InputMethodManager inputMananger = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMananger.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

b) Request focus of the `EditText` that you wish to gain focus.

```
editText.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

Comment: hello! method a does make the keyboard appear. however, it shows below the dialog fragment. how do i fix this problem?

Comment: Are you toggling the soft input from within the `DialogFragment` or the `Activity`?

Comment: I'm toggling it from the DialogFragment

Comment: Okay, try setting `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);` from within your `DialogFragment`'s `onCreateView()` method.

Comment: @Ryan - Where should I use your first method, is it inside edittext click event?

Comment: @Arvindraja I would call it wherever/whenever you need to show it. You could do it on initial load of the view (some `onCreate...()` or `onStart()` lifecycle method), or you could call it from the click event of the `EditText`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
public AlertDialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    // ...
    alertDialog.show();

    // This line is the key
    alertDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);

    return alertDialog;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
InputMethodManager imm1 = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        edt_user_name.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                edt_user_name.requestFocus();
                imm1.showSoftInput(edt_user_name, 0);
            }
        }, 100);
```

For a particular EditText e.g `edt_user_name`.

Comment: Try adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to your AndroidManifest.xml. and Remove `</request focus>` and `dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);`  If it is there

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've solved this by adding an EditText inside the fragment layout (not just RecyclerView)like this :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editFake"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:hint="@string/empty"
            android:inputType="none"
            tools:targetApi="o"
            android:background="@null"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```